# How to create array by explode to get arithmetic mean

Tags: php, arrays, math, mean, explode

i have this string

```
04.01.2021|26,140 05.01.2021|26,225 06.01.2021|26,145 07.01.2021|26,145 08.01.2021|26,165 11.01.2021|26,240 12.01.2021|26,190
```

i have like these dates into december.

As you can se there is a date (DD.MM.YY)| number XX.xxx

Id like to do arithmetic mean for every month. I know function explode which gives me array but idk how to integrate it to be able make arithmetic mean for months.

Comment: What have you got so far, can we see your code? What "_arithmetic mean_"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '04.01.2021|26,140 05.01.2021|26,225 06.01.2021|26,145 07.01.2021|26,145 08.01.2021|26,165 11.02.2021|26,240 12.02.2021|26,190';

$array = array_map(
    fn($item) => explode('|', $item),
    explode(' ', $input)
);

$months = array_reduce(
    $array,
    function ($carry, $item) {
      $carry[substr($item[0], 3)][] = str_replace(',', '',$item[1]);
      return $carry;
    },
    []
);

$averagesPerMonths = array_map(
    fn($value) => array_sum($value) / count($value),
    $months
);

print_r($averagesPerMonths);
```

The first step is to transform the input string to an array. Each value in the array is itself an array of two elements, the date and the amount. This is the intermediate result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04.01.2021
            [1] => 26,140
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05.01.2021
            [1] => 26,225
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 06.01.2021
            [1] => 26,145
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07.01.2021
            [1] => 26,145
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08.01.2021
            [1] => 26,165
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11.02.2021
            [1] => 26,240
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.02.2021
            [1] => 26,190
        )

)
```

In a second step the date part of each entry needs to be shorted to 'mm.yyyy' thereby dropping the day part. And in the amount entry the thousands separator, the comma needs to be removed, so that we have a number instead of a string. By using the 'mm.yyy' entry as key in *array_reduce* we can collect all amounts by each months. The intermediate result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [01.2021] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26140
            [1] => 26225
            [2] => 26145
            [3] => 26145
            [4] => 26165
        )

    [02.2021] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26240
            [1] => 26190
        )

)
```

In the third step the calculation of the average per months takes place. The final result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [01.2021] => 26164
    [02.2021] => 26215
)
```

Comment: Hello, ty for reply its looking good. Im getting warning 
"Undefined array key 1" in this line
$carry[substr($item[0], 3)][] = str_replace(',', '',$item[1]);
Im beginer in PHP, what else there must be please?